# How to check in bash if a function's arguments does not contain any parameters

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

### "Argument" vs. "Paramter"

First of all, let me clarify what I mean by:

> if a function's arguments does not contain any parameters

Given the following `ls` command:

```sh
$ ls -a sub_folder
```

I call `-a sub_folder` the function's *arguments* and only `-a` I call *parameter* (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788926/3459910)).

### Question

Now, in my `bash` script, how can I check if a function's arguments does not contain any parameters?

I thought of checking that no argument in `$@` starts with a `-`. But how could I do that?
I'm new to bash and therefore not experienced enough but in TypeScript I would do something like:

```js
if (args.some(arg => arg.startsWith("-"))) {
  # parameters found
} else {
  # no parameters
}
```

### What I want to do

I actually wanted to write my own `ls` function to also displays how many folders and files there are (via `count_info`). But this should only be displayed if I call `my_ls` with a `-l` parameter (in my case, all my aliases except `l` use the `-l` option).

In my `bashrc` I have the following code:

```bsh
alias l="my_ls" # the only call with no parameters
alias ll="l -l"
alias la="l -l --almost-all"
alias ls="l -lAsSh"

my_ls () {
  /bin/ls -p --color=always --group-directories-first "$@"
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then # check if there were parameters
    count_info
  fi
}
```

This works for all the normal alias calls `l`, `ll`, etc.
But as soon as I to something like `l subfolder` my function does not work properly anymore as my check `[ ! -z "$1" ]` fails.

Another solution would be to simply test if there is a `-l` parameter but how can I do that? Especially with also having parameter combinations like `-lAsSh` in mind.

Comment: The terminology you're using here is nonstandard. Applying the terminology in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788926/3459910), "-a" and "sub_folder" are the arguments, and `$1` and `$2` are the parameters that receive them. (Note that shell functions don't have explicit signatures; they sort of have implicit signatures of `$1, $2, $3, ...`) The standard terms for arguments like `-l` are "flag" and "option".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check this in a completely generic way, because even two programs using the same type of option parser will still have different expectations. (And of course not all programs use the same syntax at all.)

For example, `--color=always` is obviously a parameter that takes a value (in the getopt_long syntax). But how about `--color always`? One program might consume "always" as the value of the parameter, but another program might use "--color" as a boolean parameter and treat "always" as a standalone positional argument. Both are valid ways to specify the same thing.

(In ls, "--color" takes an *optional* value, so `--color always` will leave the "always" argument as a file name to list… but "--format" takes a *required* value, and if you use `--format long` it will consume the argument as an option value.)

So your check needs to exactly duplicate what `ls` itself does – you'll need to have a list of all parameters (short and long) which require a value (but not those where the value is optional), and if you see an option which you know takes a required value you'll know that the following item should be ignored.

(Similarly, getopt_long allows `--name` to be shortened to `--nam` or even `--na`, so your code needs to account for that as well. It also needs to know that a lone `--` stops parameter processing, and even arguments that begin with a dash are no longer treated as parameters beyond that point.)

In fact, it would be easiest for you to *actually* use an option parsing library that claims to be compatible with the getopt_long() function from Glibc. (But for example, Python's argparse wouldn't work as it handles optional values differently than ls would.)

This is actually easier within bash, by calling the `/bin/getopt` tool (not to be confused with the `getopts` bash built-in!). It will actually use getopt_long() and will sort all arguments so that you first have options neatly split out, then a `--`, and finally non-option arguments.

- Input: `-abT8 one --color two --format three --size four`
- Output: `-a -b -T 8 --color "" --format three --size -- one two four`

With this, all you need to check is whether there is anything in the output that follows the `--` argument. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

short="abcdfghiklmnopqrstuvw:xABCDFGHI:LNQRST:UXZ1"
long="all,almost-all,author,escape,block-size:,ignore-backups,color::,\
directory,dired,classify,file-type,format:,full-time,group-directories\
-first,no-group,human-readable,si,dereference-command-line,dereference\
-command-line-symlink-to-dir,hide:,hyperlink::,indicator-style:,inode,\
ignore:,kibibytes,dereference,numeric-uid-gid,literal,indicator-style:\
,hide-control-chars,show-control-chars,quote-name,quoting-style:,rever\
se,recursive,size,sort:,time:,time-style:,tabsize:,width:,context,help\
,version"
parsed=$(getopt -o "$short" -l "$long" -- "$@") || exit

eval "args=($parsed)"
declare -p args   # print the array's contents

end=0; found=0
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
        if (( end )); then
                echo "found non-option arg '$arg'"
                exit 1
        elif [[ $arg == "--" ]]; then
                end=1
        fi
done
echo "did not find any non-option args"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out about `getops` to properly split up all my parameters and this is what I ended up with:

```bsh
my_ls () {
  /bin/ls -p --color=always --group-directories-first "$@"

  local OPTIND option
  while getopts ":l" option; do
    if [[ "$option" == "l" ]]; then
      count_info
    fi
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
}
```